# Difficulty understanding Javascript composing in this function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Im following this course and came across this problem

```
const compose = (f, g) => (a) => f(g(a));
const add1 = (num) => num + 1;
const add5 = (num) => num + 5;
compose(add1, add5)(10)
```

As i understand it `g(a)` gets run first so `num = 1` makes `1` for `g` and `10` for `a`, that makes it `f(1(10))`.
But how does the `1` and the `10` know to add, why doesn't it multiply or minus ?

Comment: `compose(add1, add5)(10)` -> `a === 10`, `g === add5`, `f === add1` -> `add1(add5(10))`

Answer (score 4):

> that makes it `f(1(10))`

This is not true. Because `1(10)` is not even a valid javascript syntax. When the value `10` is passed to the function `g` its returns five more than the value which is `15`. This is because its defined in the function `add5` which is passed as `g` to the `compose` function

The value returned from the above function call which is `15` is then passed to `f` which is `add1`. So in the last it returns `16`

> But how does the `1` and the `10` know to add, why doesn't it multiply or minus.

You are using `+` inside the functions passed. If you will use `-` or `*` it will then multiply or minus

Comment: "g its returns one more" should be "g it returns five more"

Comment: ive tried to replace with a * or - in a console and it says its invalid syntax

Comment: What you replaced with `*` or `-`, You need to replace `+` in side the function

Comment: @JohannDavelDeBeer `const add1 = (num) => num * 1;
`

Answer (score -1):

This is a technique known as currying.

Your `compose` function takes two functions as arguments.

Those functions each take a single `num` argument.

When you call `compose(add1, add5)(10)` the expression is parsed as the following:

Give me the output of calling `add1` on the output of calling `add5(10)`. In Javascript syntax, this looks like, `f(g(a))`, i.e. `add1(add5(10))`.

If you follow and evaluate the expressions in order, it goes:

`compose(f, g)(a) === f(g(a))`

`compose(add1, add5)(10) === add1(add5(10)) === add1(15) === 16`

Comment: There's no currying going on in any of this code. An example of currying would be `const add = x => y => x + y; add(1)(2); // -> 3`. What we have in this sample code is simply the composition of two unary functions.

Comment: "*This is a technique known as currying.*" [this is simple classical functional composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science))